# Implementing long-polling ajax with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, long-polling, padrino

I have plenty of experience with Sinatra and Padrino. I use datamapper for database calls so before i learned that there is a programming model called comet programming, to implement a simple chat system, i was sending Ajax requests every moment to server from user's browser.

Now i watched Facebook's system for a while and as long as i can see, my browser is sending a request to server, server holding my request, and when there is a new message for me, it answers the request. After that my browser starts another request as soon as possible and this loop continues forever. I want to implement a system that mimics this behavior.

Client side is not a big problem, am pretty good at Ajax with Jquery, but i have no idea how to make a request wait until there is an insert in my database?

Comment: Did you try socket.io for the polling part?

Answer (score 2):

there are a infinite alternative to mimic FB, it's quite common in ruby http://faye.jcoglan.com

or if you don't want to take care about the server side you should check http://pusher.com

There are only few of a planet of choices.

Comment: faye looks promisin, i cannot see any reason why should i add another layer like pusher

Comment: yep I agree, pusher is useful if you don't want to take care about the server side code